# Video streaming lags and creates audio buzz

Tags: audio, video, streaming

To begin with, I need to state that I have *actually* done search on this. All I could find were various solutions that didn't apply to me, and in the end it seemed like it is very specific to individual computers. So I decided to post here and get individual help.

Basically as the title says, my video streaming, on any website, using any browser, creates a lag. Not only for the video, or the browser, but the mouse itself too. Point being that it creates lag outside the scope of the page as well.
**My understanding** is that it has something to do with Flash Player. And because of that understanding, I updated my Flash Player yesterday, and it didn't help at all.

I've also cleared/deleted my temporary files, and used CCleaner to clear up any excess files just for good measures as my computer being clean, I've also cleared the caches.

**Note:** This is not a buffering matter, I know when it's buffering and when it isn't. **However,** it may be helpful to let you know that when the video has fully buffered, the lag is reduced to almost none.

Comment: What about other devices, you have the same problem?

Comment: @Santeador I assume you mean streaming videos on other devices, like my phone or other PC's, and the answer is no I don't. All other devices stream fine.

Comment: The one that has the problem is connected via ethernet cable? If not, try to disable Wi-fi and connect it directly to the router.

Comment: @Santeador Okay, I did that just now, and the video played without a problem. I then enabled WiFi again and tried to playback a video, and it played without any lag. Is it safe to conclude that all that was needed was a disable and enable of the WiFi adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer update**: I realized that something might be throttling my Internet on my laptop, and I diagnosed for it, ended up being something that actually makes sense. My anti-virus' firewall. The settings had changed to default for some reason, and the firewall scanned everything. So I changed it back to what I had set it before, and the issue doesn't happen at all anymore.

**TL;DR**: Check what software is throttling your PC's connection, in my case it was Bitdefender Firewall. Disable it or tweak it so it doesn't happen.

Comment: Well... My next intended answer was: ¿What are your Wi-Fi settings? Is signal strength enough where computer is located? You need Wi-Fi G and 54Mbps for correct streaming. Wi-Fi N and more than 100Mbps for HD streaming, you can almost make and equal need of HD specs: 720p >> 72Mbps, 1080p >> 100Mbps.

Comment: Thank you for your input, and I'm sure it'll help someone with the same problem like it helped for me.

Comment: Enjoy! As you say, if someone gets here with the same issue, one of the best streaming softwares, explain it better witch non-techie speech: https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200484903-Network-Requirements ;-)

Comment: @Santeador I think we have to follow up on this, of course not if you don't want to, but I decided I should come back, because the problem is back again, and even with what we did yesterday, it's not working.

Comment: Go to www.speedtest.net and share your results, please.

Comment: @Santeador I was just over at speedtest, as I thought I should answer your previous questions, and I discovered something, for whatever reason, my Internet download speed has dropped to 7.40 Mbps, from the previous 25 Mbps. I have no idea why, but I'm assuming this is the problem?

Comment: Yes it is. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Santeador I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: laptop? wi-fi dongle? model?

Comment: @Santeador Yes, laptop, Sony Vaio VPCEH26EG. But the thing is, these things shouldn't matter since this has been happening since the last 4 days. I suppose you realize I'm replying (2 hours later, sorry about that btw), I contacted my ISP and told them why my speed has dropped, because the thing is, I shouldn't even be 25Mbps, I have a fiber account with my ISP at 100Mbps, so I took the matter into their hands. If you'd like, I can update you here once I've come to a resolution with them.

Comment: OK, let me know, because that model doesn't seem to has oficial drivers compatibility for Windows 10 http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/VPCEH26EG. Do a speedtest through cable to be sure the problem is not Wi-Fi. I've experienced some troubles in Windows 10 with old Wi-Fi chipsets or with de wrong motherboard chipset drivers...

Comment: @Santeador with cable my speed goes up to 34Mbps, but then again, that's still not the full Internet's potential. Maybe it could be because I have a CAT 5 cable, but as I said, about the Internet connection, I'm taking that up with my ISP and will let you know how it goes. As for my laptop, yeah it's pretty outdated and there are no official drivers for Windows 10, but I've been using Windows 10 on it with no problems since the Technical Preview of Windows 10.

Comment: With that info, WAN connection seems the only thing to fix. Good luck with your ISP, let me know if its get solved ;-)

Comment: @Santeador Hey, update here. The problem with my ISP still stands, but I need better cable and router (one that's capable of Mbps for many users) before taking it up with them. However, I fixed the problem **for good**. I realized that something might be throttling my Internet on my laptop, and I diagnosed for it, ended up being something that actually makes sense. My anti-virus' firewall. The settings had changed to default for some reason, and the firewall scanned everything. So I changed it back to what I had set it before, and the issue doesn't happen at all anymore.

Comment: Great news! Good luck with your ISP.